# validacion de usuario y administracion (login)

Tags: php

necesito ayuda no me valida el tipo de usuario,alguien me puede ayudar,el tipo de usuario son dos administrador y usuario y me sale error

```
<?php
session_start();
include ("conexion.php");

$correo = $_POST['CORR'];
$clave =  $_POST['CLAV'];
$tipo =  $_POST['TIPO'];

$verificar_correo = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM personal where correo_empresarial = '$correo' AND clave='$clave'AND tipo_usuario='$tipo'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($verificar_correo)>0)
{ 
    if ($verificar_correo['tipo_usuario'] == 'Administrador'){ 
        $_SESSION['USU']=$verificar_correo;
        echo '<script>
        location.href="principal.php"
        </script>';
        exit;

    }

}elseif(mysqli_num_rows($verificar_correo)>0){
    if ($verificar_correo['tipo_usuario'] == 'Usuario'){ 
        $_SESSION['USU']=$verificar_correo;
        echo '<script>
        location.href="principal2.php"
        </script>';
        exit;

    }
}


mysqli_close($conexion);


?>
```

Comment: ¿No te falta un fetch por ahí?

Comment: Hola Alan y bienvenido, por favor edita el título de tu pregunta para que resuma el problema específico y así tu publicación sea mejor recibida por la comunidad. Puedes [visitar el centro de ayuda para más información](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: y como seria  el codigo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start();
include ("conexion.php");

$correo = $_POST['CORR'];
$clave =  $_POST['CLAV'];
$tipo =  $_POST['TIPO'];

$verificar_correo = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM personal where correo_empresarial = '$correo' AND clave='$clave'AND tipo_usuario='$tipo'");

$rows=array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($verificar_correo)) {
  $rows[]=$row;
}
if(mysqli_num_rows($verificar_correo)>0)
{ 
  foreach($rows as $row) {  
    if ($row['tipo_usuario'] == 'Administrador'){ 
        $_SESSION['USU']=$verificar_correo;
        echo '<script>
        location.href="principal.php"
        </script>';
        exit;
    }
  }

}elseif(mysqli_num_rows($verificar_correo)>0){
  foreach($rows as $row) {  
    if ($row['tipo_usuario'] == 'Usuario'){ 
        $_SESSION['USU']=$verificar_correo;
        echo '<script>
        location.href="principal2.php"
        </script>';
        exit;
    }
  }
}  
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Para recoger los datos de la consulta tienes que recogerlos con un fetch, como el [fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) que te devuelve un array asociativo(el indice es el nombre de la columna).
El fetch te devuelve un array con las filas resultantes, con el foreach las recorres y vas comparando el tipo del usuario.

No se que quieres meter en la sesión pero no le puedes meter la consulta directamente.

Comment: muchas gracias con ese codigo ya puedo solucionar mi problema

Answer (score 0):

Estás evaluando en tus dos condicionales lo mismo.

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($verificar_correo)>0){ 
   //Primera condicion
}elseif(mysqli_num_rows($verificar_correo)>0){
   //Segunda condicion que evalua lo mismo que la primera
}
```

La forma correcta seria:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($verificar_correo) == 0){ 
   //Datos incorrectos, realizar acciones.
}else{
    //Datos correctos, logear usuario.
}
```

Al igual, es necesario filtrar las cadenas que el usuario puede ingresar para prevenir inyecciones de SQL.

```
$variable = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['VARIABLE']);
```

**Inyeccion SQL:** https://likegeeks.com/es/prevenir-la-inyeccion-de-sql/

Comment: sería un complemento mas que perfecto que no solo use dicha función sino que además maneje consultas preparadas

Comment: y como seria el codigo en si ?

Comment: Puedes saber más de las [sentencias preparadas](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) en el enlace. La respuesta a tu error son las condiciones duplicadas, lo demás entra como consejo para mejorar tu código.